# ax.plot_wireframe error when values for X or Y axis are strings

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a surface 3D graph for my website with matplotlib, but I am getting an error. Here is the source code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

X = np.array([ '4K', '8K' ])
Y = np.array([ 1, 4 ])
Z = np.array([[0.1925, 0.1848], [0.1807, 0.1966]])

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)

plt.show()
```

The error I am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wire3d.py", line 21, in <module>
    ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py", line 415, in wrapper
    return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 1908, in plot_wireframe
    self.auto_scale_xyz(X, Y, Z, had_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 652, in auto_scale_xyz
    self.xy_dataLim.update_from_data_xy(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 967, in update_from_data_xy
    path = Path(xy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/path.py", line 129, in __init__
    vertices = _to_unmasked_float_array(vertices)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 1298, in _to_unmasked_float_array
    return np.asarray(x, float)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '4K'
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify what 4K and 8K means:

```
X = np.array([ 4000, 8000 ])
```

If you are interest in show "4K" and "8K" in the x axis you can add `ax.set_xticks(X, [ '4K', '8K' ])` before showing the figure.

This is the right code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

X = np.array([ 4000, 8000 ])
Y = np.array([ 1, 4 ])
Z = np.array([[0.1925, 0.1848], [0.1807, 0.1966]])

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)
ax.set_xticks(X, [ '4K', '8K' ])

plt.show()
```